# HashMap not adding all keys

Tags: java, hashmap

I am adding strings to a `HashMap<String, ChartSeries>` but it doesn't add all the strings. It does however change the size integer of the hashmap:
[image]

As you can see it says `size:6` but when you look into the table it only holds 4 objects.

This is my code:

```
for (CaseTypeActivationAmount CTAM : caseTypeActivationAmounts) {
    ChartSeries cs;
    if (!caseTypes.containsKey(CTAM.getOmschrijving())) {
        if (CTAM.getOmschrijving() != null) {
            cs = new ChartSeries(CTAM.getOmschrijving());
        } else {
            cs = new ChartSeries(" ");
        }

        caseTypes.put(CTAM.getOmschrijving(), cs);
    } else {
        cs = caseTypes.get(CTAM.getOmschrijving());
    }
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");
    cs.set(dateFormat.format(CTAM.getDate()), CTAM.getAmount());
}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: You're asking a question based on an entirely mistaken premise. If you had done any testing or any research, rather than trying to guess at `HashMap`'s implementation logic, you would see everything works fine. I've removed my downvote.

Comment: @shmosel I use this data to fill up a chart but it is not showing anything. I went debugging and couldn't find all the objects so that's why I asked it. I know how a Hashmap works but I thought that strings had an unique hash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> when you look into the table it only holds 4 objects.

The table does hold six objects. However, due to hash collisions, it holds them in only four [separate chains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Separate_chaining).

You can see what's going on in the debugger: open the value of each node, and examine the next value. You will find that either (1) two of the six nodes have a second item, or (2) one of the six nodes has two additional items in its chain, for the overall count of six objects.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are missing something. Each position of the backing array of the `HashMap` can hold a reference to a single `HashMap.Node`. However, that `Node` does not necessarily contain just a single `Map.Entry`. It can contain a linked-list or tree of Entries which were mapped to the same bucket (bit) of the `HashMap`.

Therefore the 4 `Node`s you are seeing do not correspond with 4 Entries.

If you iterate over the `entrySet` of the map you'll see all 6 Entries.

Answer (score 1):

Those are `Node`s, actually LinkedNodes. The hashcode of some of the keys are equal, and you get more then one entry in the same bucket.

One of the `HashMap$Node` that you see is actually :

```
 HashMap$Node -> HashMap$Node(next)...
```

Here is how it `actually` looks internally:

```
static class Node<K,V> implements Map.Entry<K,V> {
    final int hash;
    final K key;
    V value;
    Node<K,V> next; // NOTICE the next here
```

When you go `after` a certain limit, those Nodes are going to become TreeNodes (holding an entire Tree of Entries) in a single bucket.